# Canvas is rendering after the scene in Unity on device

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

I'm developping a 3D app with Unity. The app should start on a splash screen canvas, then should show the loaded scene.

Everything works well on Editor. But when I try on a real device (iphone7), the canvas displays very lately: Between Unity splash screen and my splash screen, I can see during 0.5 second the avatar as a T shape (not animated) and an empty backgound. And then my splash screen.

What I want:
Unity splashscreen > My Splashscreen > the scene fully loaded

What I see:
Unity splashscreen > the scene not completely loaded > my splash screen > the scene fully loaded

How can I tell Unity to render the Canvas earlier?

**EDIT**
My canvas is just in front of the camera, my 3D objects too.
I reproduced the problem on a new scene, very simplified (Image is a simple opaque background, no sprite is configured): The cube and blank bg still appear quickly before Canvas...

[image: scene]

Comment: you're loading the scene manually or your splashscreen canvas is just in front? of the camera on the same scene?

Comment: The second. See my edits.

Comment: Is there some script that controls that? Is it possible the camera isn't found correctly in the beginning?

Comment: In this simple project, there is no script at all. I ended with creating a splashscreen scene, with an opaque background with the same color as the splash image. The problem remains (logo unity > plain color > Canvas image), but is less visible.

Answer (score 1):

Move Canvas under all the rest, as the hierarchy goes from down to top!

Comment: Nope sorry, the scene load exactly the same way